# Switch with regex in powershell specifying the IP address

Tags: regex, powershell, switch-statement

I have to set 3 variables depending on the IP address.

I discovered that I can use switch with -regex, but I don't know how to check if address is between two addresses.

```
$ip = (get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration|Where {$_.Ipaddress.length -gt 1}).ipaddress[0]
switch -regex ($ip) 
{ 
    "address 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255" { $val = 3; } 
    "address 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.100" { $val = 1; } 
    "address 192.168.1.101-192.168.1.200" { $val = 4; } 
    "address 192.168.1.201-192.168.1.255" { $val = 5; } 
    default { exit }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think regex is the best way of handling this. I'd probably do something like this

```
$ip = (get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration|Where {$_.Ipaddress.length -gt 1}).ipaddress.split('.')
switch ($ip) 
{ 
    {$ip[2] -eq 0} { $val = 3; } #match anything in 192.168.0.1-255
    {$ip[3] -in 1..100} { $val = 1; } 
    {$ip[3] -in 101..200} { $val = 4; } 
    {$ip[3] -in 201..255} { $val = 5; } 
    default { exit }
}
$val
```

If your IP blocks are different than what was provided in the example it would just be a matter of adjusting the switch conditions to match the appropriate octets